# WPF - BindingExpression path Error with Nested ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I know that there are different topics on this argument, but I can't still find a solution. 
Here the specific problem:

I wrote several WPF `UserControl`s. Each `UserControl` has its own `ViewModel`. The `Xaml` view is placed in separated `Xaml` templates (`Themes` folder).

There is a "special" control that hosts some of these custom `UserControl`s. Here's the scenario

**SpecialControl.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Controls">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SpecialControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            [...]
            <ControlA  PropertyA="{Binding Path=DataSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            [...]
```

No Problem with `PropertyA`, because it is binded to the `SpecialControlViewModel.DataSource`.

**ControlA.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Controls">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SpecialControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            [...]
            <TextBlock Name="PART_MyTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyTextProperty  Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource qualityGraphicConverter}}" />
```

Where `MyTextProperty` is defined in the `ControlA` `ViewModel`.

When I run the application all works normally, but in the Output log I can read something like:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyTextProperty ' property not found on 'object' ''SpecialControlViewModel' (HashCode=8043914)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.MyTextProperty; DataItem='ControlA' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='PART_MyTextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

How can I fix my binding to avoid these messages?

Comment: Are they `UserControl`s of `CustomControl`s... there's a big difference. *How can I fix this?*... that depends where your `MyTextProperty` is actually defined... you didn't show us, so we can't help you yet.

Comment: they are "WPF UserControl". Every UserControl has its own ViewModel; MyTextProperty is defined in ControlAViewModel. I'll update the question.

Comment: Then your problem is simply that you have set an instance of your `SpecialControlViewModel` as the `DataContext` of your `SpecialControl` instead of an instance of your `ControlAViewModel`, or that you're trying to data bind to a property of a view model that is out of scope. What is the connection between the two view models? And why have you created two `Style`s for your `SpecialControl`?

Comment: If one is inside the other, perhaps you need a `RelativeSource Binding` more like this: `Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyTextProperty  Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:ControlA}}, Converter={StaticResource qualityGraphicConverter}}" />`

`

Comment: SpecialControl is a UserControl that contains some of the others Controls plus custom features. ControlA can exists even outside from SpecialControl. So ControlA has its own viewModel while SpecialControl has its own viewModel. WPF resolves the binding at runtime, so all works correctly but I suppose that this is not the right way to se my Bindings.

Comment: @Sheridan no, no..you're wrong. There is only one (1) style for SpecialControl. If you read carefully, the second style is for ControlA. The vievmodel for SpecialControl has to be SpecialControlViewModel, while the viewmodel for ControlA has to be ControlAViewModel. You can't set broccoli view model for a banana object, don't you? :) As a matter of fact, at runtime the binding works without problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70123/discussion-between-riccardo-and-sheridan).